# SQL query error#1064

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT students.name, subjects.sub
FROM students INNER JOIN (subjects INNER JOIN test ON subjects.IDsub = test.IDsub) ON  students.IDstu = test.IDstu
WHERE ((test.date)=#1/21/2013#);
```

Everytime I execute this query I get this message:

> '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

I think the problem is in the date format because if I execute this one:

```
SELECT students.name, subjects.sub
FROM students INNER JOIN (subjects INNER JOIN test ON subjects.IDsub = test.IDsub) ON students.IDstu = test.IDstu
WHERE ((test.IDsub)=4);
```

Everything works fine!

In the database there are 3 tables: "students", "test", "subjects".

Comment: i dont see a limit clause in your query

Comment: PhpMyAdmin added it, I'm sure. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

date should be like this, i.e. instead of `#` make use of `'`

```
SELECT students.name, subjects.sub
FROM students INNER JOIN 
(subjects INNER JOIN test ON subjects.IDsub = test.IDsub) 
  ON  students.IDstu = test.IDstu
WHERE ((test.date)='1/21/2013');
```

Answer (score 0):

[str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT students.name, subjects.sub
FROM students INNER JOIN (subjects INNER JOIN test ON subjects.IDsub = test.IDsub) ON  students.IDstu = test.IDstu
WHERE ((test.date)=str_to_date('1/21/2013');
```

The other issue I see is that the use of the pound sign `#` is not a valid way to create a string lookup in mysql.  You want to use the single quote `'`

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin adds a snippet of SQL to each command to limit the number of records returned.

```
LIMIT 0, 30
```

I'd remove the semicolon from the end of your query, because otherwise, SQL thinks this extra snippet is another query.

```
WHERE ((test.date)=#1/21/2013#)
```

Also, I've never seen the `#` symbol used in a query like that, you might have a problem there.

Edit: According to everyone else (who ignored the actual SQL Error...), the `#` is not valid, use quotes instead.

Another Edit: Actually, the `#` notation seems valid.

[Select query with date condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183180/select-query-with-date-condition)