# How to use datetime picker to retrieve data from ms access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetimepicker

I am creating one application in C# in which I am using datetimepicker control. I have created a database in MS Access which contains one table with `Date_Entry, Emp_No, Emp_Name, In_Time, Out_Time` columns.

Now I want to retrieve these data in textbox by clicking date on datetimepicker control. This date is point the date in `Date_Entry` field of database and fetch the data according to that date.

How to do it?

```
 private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 try
 {
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection    ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0,DataSource=C:\\Users\\jd\\Desktop\\Attendance.mdb");
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Attendance_Details WHERE Date_Entry=" +     dateTimePicker1.Value + "", conn);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds, "Attendance_Details");
 txtDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
 txtEmpNo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
 txtEmpName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
 txtInTime.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
 txtOutTime.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: you want to retrieve data again with date of txtDate.Text??? whats problem in above code?

Comment: no from database ...field name Date_Entry

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in above code. I have refined it. Now it will work.

**Following Should be the code:**

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 try
 {

 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection    ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0,DataSource=C:\\Users\\jd\\Desktop\\Attendance.mdb");
 con.open();
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Attendance_Details WHERE Date_Entry=@dtpDate", conn);
 cmd.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@dtpDate", dateTimePicker1.Value);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 txtDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
 txtEmpNo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
 txtEmpName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
 txtInTime.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
 txtOutTime.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
 con.close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 finally
 {
   con.close();
 }
 }
 }
```

Hope Its helpful.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am getting this error
Error 1 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Addwithvalue' and no extension method 'Addwithvalue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\jay.desai\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Attendance Module\Attendance Module\Form1.cs 29 32 Attendance Module

Comment: Unrecognized database format 'C:\Users\jd\Desktop\Attendance.mdb

Answer (score 0):

To answer your problem about the "Error 1   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Addwithvalue' and no extension method 'Addwithvalue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection'"

...did you Google? https://www.google.nl/search?q=Addwithvalue It actually shows you what's wrong.

About selecting dates: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183180/select-query-with-date-condition). It can be tricky. Make sure you use the right syntax.

Comment: got it...i got new error Unrecognized database format 'C:\Users\jd\Desktop\Attendance.mdb

Comment: Change your connectionstring to     @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0,DataSource=C:\Users\jd\Desktop\Attendance.mdb"

And what kind of Access-database is it?

Comment: Access 2002 - 2003 format database
Now i got other error @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0,DataSource=C:\Users\jd\Desktop\Attendance.mdb‌​" provider is not register in your local machine

Comment: Here's a solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/464072/The-Microsoft-Jet-OLEDB-4-0-provider-is-not-regist