# Select query based on date format in access using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I want to fetch data from a database that falls between two dates.

**The code:**

```
 con1.Open()
    Dim re As String = ""
    Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Dim d2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select lno,pname,mdue,ramt from Due where ddate >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(d1) + "' and ddate<= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(d2) + "' and ramt='0'", con1)
    Dim da As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While (da.Read())

        re = re & "  " & da("lno").ToString.PadRight(30) & " " & da("pname").ToString.PadLeft(10) & "  " & da("mdue").ToString.PadLeft(10) & Chr(13)
    End While
```

I get a data type mismatch error.  The datatype for date is `Date/Time` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting to string before assiging to your `DateTime` variables!

Try

```
con1.Open()
Dim re As String = ""
Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
Dim d2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker3.Value
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select lno,pname,mdue,ramt from Due where ddate >= #" & String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", d1) & "# and ddate<= #" & String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", d2) & "# and ramt='0'", con1)
Dim da As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While (da.Read())
    re = re & "  " & da("lno").ToString.PadRight(30) & " " & da("pname").ToString.PadLeft(10) & "  " & da("mdue").ToString.PadLeft(10) & Chr(13)
End While
```

---

You should also probably use `&` as the concatenation operator ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx

Comment: According to this, you must surround your dates with `#` rather than `'` ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/4183357/5040941 ... I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Glad to help. Relearned something about dates in access myself! :0)