# How to get records within specified date using datetimepocker

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datetimepicker

[image: List of Inquiries Form]

I have a question about my Inquiry Form... I am using VB2005 and MS Access as its database. Here's my code:

```
    Private Sub frmViewInquiries_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim varFromDate As Date = Me.dtpFromDate.Value.ToShortString
Dim varToDate As Date = Me.dtpToDate.Value.ToString
Dim MyDS As New DataSet

Dim MyDA As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblStudentInfoInq WHERE DateInquired >= "& varFromDate &" AND DateInquired <= "& varToDate &"", MyConn)
MyDa.Fill(MyDS, "tblStudentInfoInq")

Me.dgvInquiryList.DataSource = MyDS.Tables("tblStudentInfoInq")

End Sub
```

I want to get the list of inquiries that inquired within FROM and TO DateTimePicker date value. When I debug the program with that code, I can't get the record from the database since I have records inquired on March 7 and 8, that is supposed to appear on my DataGridView. Is my SQL syntax correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that Sir. How can I add that function to my code?

Comment: Use the `Between` function... For example `"SELECT * FROM tblStudentInfoInq WHERE DateInquired Between "& varFromDate &" AND " & varToDate`

Comment: find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183180/select-query-with-date-condition

Comment: I got this error:
ERROR [42000][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'DateInquired BETWEEN 3/7/2016 AND DateInquired 3/9/2016'.

Comment: You have an extra `DateInquired` in that...

Comment: Got it... Thanks @T.S.

Comment: Oh yeah the dang `#` signs! I was thinking Sql...