# php - sql select query where date is greater then, including php variables

Tags: php, sql, date, ms-access, pdo

Already read all the other treads regarding this matter, but I cant find an answer that includes php variables.

I want to select the first 100 new records after a certain date of my database. I can't get it to work.

```
$connStr =
    'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
    'Dbq='.$ini_project['general']['document_location'].';';

$dbh = new PDO($connStr);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$time = strtotime('6-8-2017 21:52:00');

$date = date('j-n-Y H:i:s',$time);

$sql1  = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM `$table_name $table_number` WHERE Systeemtijd > `$date`";

$result = $dbh->query($sql1);

while($row = $result->fetch()) {
      print_r($row);
}
```

I'm able to select records from another field in the table (WHERE value > 200 for example) but not based on the date column in my table.
I also tried without `` and:

```
$sql1  = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM `$table_name $table_number` WHERE Systeemtijd > DATE `$date`";
```

All give the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression 'Systeemtijd > 6-8-2017 21:52:00'. (SQLPrepare[0] at
>   ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:206)' in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.30-1\apache2\htdocs\php7\DataBuilt\Larissa_Connector\data_uploader.php:65
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.30-1\apache2\htdocs\php7\DataBuilt\Larissa_Connector\data_uploader.php(65):
>   PDO->query('SELECT TOP 100 ...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.30-1\apache2\htdocs\php7\DataBuilt\Larissa_Connector\data_uploader.php
>   on line 65

Comment: It is not mysql. It is MS-access

Comment: I guess you have to use single quotes arround `$date` not backticks

Comment: Doyou have blanks in your table oame or what should `$table_name $table_number` be?

Comment: oh yes, its indeed MS-access. will change it. and yes I have blanks in my table names. the access file and tables are automatically generated, so I cant change that.

Comment: @Jens single qoutes dont do the trick. same error.

Comment: Do you need to wrap the table name like this `[$table_name $table_number]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly the table name works like this with other columns of the table, thats not the problem

Comment: Ok I will stop guessing. My Access is very rusty and out of date

Comment: Found the answer! Forgot that is was MS-access, so $date needs to be #$date# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183180/select-query-with-date-condition

Comment: @LoesVisser that's not correct, see my answer. You will run into problems because the order is incorrect. It will run, but interpret the 3rd of february as the 2nd of march, because you're inserting the day and month in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Access SQL should be either `#yyyy/mm/dd#` or `#mm/dd/yyyy#`. Any other date format causes problems.

```
$date = date('#y/n/j- H:i:s#',$time);

$sql1  = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM `$table_name $table_number` WHERE Systeemtijd > $date";
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables like this is not a good idea, you always have to be aware of how to correctly escape them, try using PDO::prepare:

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM $full_table_name 
  WHERE Systeemtijd  > :date";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':date' => $date);
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php