# any way to imp sum of field from access to excel vba

Tags: excel

I have a access db in H:\ drive, path given in Sheet1 cell H1, i want to import the sum of data of field SPs having same date. date is given in cell A1 of sheet1. the same is to be repeated daily with todays / current date. can I get the answer in cell B1.
The code is strucked at row Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

```
Public Sub sum()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Dim countfrmdb As String
Dim currentdte As Date
currentdte = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")  
dbPath = Sheet1.Range("H1").Value

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & dbPath

strSql = "SELECT SUM(SPs) As Total FROM Survey WHERE Date = '" & currentdte & "'"

cn.Open strConnection
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
countfrmdb = rs.Fields(0)
MsgBox (countfrmdb)
End Sub
```

Comment: I Am Using MS office 2013

Comment: You have to use # before and after the date: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183357/16578424

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select query with date condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183180/select-query-with-date-condition)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the microsoft ActiveX DATAObjects 6.0 library in preferences  & used the following code & worked like a charm

```
Sub Importf()


'Declaring the necessary variables.
Dim cnn As Object 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rs As Object 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim var As Range
Dim var1 As Range
'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:

'Disable screen flickering.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

dbPath = Sheet1.Range("h1").Value
Set var = Sheet1.Range("a1")

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection


cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

SQL = "SELECT SUM(SPs), sum(Kms) As Total FROM Survey WHERE Date like" & Format(var, "\#dd-mmm-yy\#")

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset


rs.Open SQL, cnn

'Check if the recordset is empty.
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
'Close the recordet and the connection.
rs.Close
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
'Enable the screen.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'In case of an empty recordset display an error.
MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
Exit Sub
End If

'Write the reocrdset values in the sheet.
Sheet1.Range("b1").CopyFromRecordset rs

'Close the recordset and the connection.
rs.Close
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'Update the worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Inform the user that the macro was executed successfully.

MsgBox "Congratulation the data has been successfully Imported", vbInformation, "Data Imported"
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Import_Data"

End Sub
```